# append element in array or in pandas dataframe

Tags: arrays, pandas, loops, for-loop

```
rmse =  []
r2 =  []
columns = ['col1','col2', ... , 'col26']
lrm = LinearRegression()
```

> ```
> for i in columns:
>     X= df[i].values.reshape(-1,1)
>     for j in columns:
>         y= df[j].values.reshape(-1,1)
>
>         X_std = stdsc.fit_transform(X)
>         y_std = stdsc.fit_transform(y)
>
>         lrm.fit(X_std,y_std)
>         y_pred = lrm.predict(X_std)
>
>         rmse.append(np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_std,y_pred)))
>         r2.append(metrics.r2_score(y_std, y_pred))
> ```

with my code I have a list of rmse and r2 score but I want to make it as an array or pandas dataframe so
I can visualize in a heatmap.

what function should I use for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can work it out like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'rmse':rmse, 'r2':r2})

print(df.head())
```

there are more fun ways to solve it see [**here**](https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/01/how-to-create-pandas-dataframe-from-multiple-lists/)

Comment: I think this just make the elements in list in pandas data frame. what I want is an array of 26x26. when you see my loop, it just generate a list of 26*26=676 elements

Answer (score 0):

by array of 26*26 you mean a  2d matrix of two lists?

if yes then you can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.column_stack((rmse,r2))
```